# Microsoft Project, use vba to delete tasks

Tags: vba, ms-project

Sorry if this is an easy question, I just started using vba with MS Project.

I am trying to cycle through all the tasks in a MS Project file and delete a task if it meets a certain criteria.  The problem happens after a task is deleted, it seems like the j task variable gets set to Nothing, which screws everything up.  Any idea how I can do this?

```
For Each j In prj.Tasks

    If j.Text10 = "1" Or j.Text10 = "2" Then ' If criteria is met

        SelectRow Row:=j ' Select the row
        EditDelete        ' Delete the row

    End If
Next j
```

Comment: use a for x = maxTasks to 1 step -1 that way your counter doesn't lose it's place

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is how I have done it in the past, check through all tasks in the project.

I'm not 100% sure on the syntax as it's been a while since I've worked with project and i copied this from vb.net

```
Dim T as Task

For Each T In Application.Tasks
    If T.Text10 = "1" Or T.Text10 = "2" Then
        T.Delete
    End If
Next
```

after looking at your code again it looks like you just need to change

```
.... Then
    j.Delete
End if
```

Comment: That was it. Thank you

Comment: if that answer worked for you could please accept it as the answer, it helps others who have similar questions to find a working solution.